# What's the value of the area of the triangle $ABC$ below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, geometric-construction, geometric-transformation

For reference: Calculate the area of ​​triangle $ABC$; if $ED = 16$;
$AB = 10$ and $D = \angle15^o$(Answer:$20$)
[image]

My progress:

I didn't get much.

$\triangle ECD - (15^o, 75^o) \implies EC = 4(\sqrt6-\sqrt2), CD = 4(\sqrt 6+\sqrt 2)$

Incenter Th.

$\triangle ABD: \frac{AC}{CI}=\frac{10+BD}{16+EA}\\
S_{CDE} = 4(\sqrt6-\sqrt2)4(\sqrt6+\sqrt2) = 32$

I thought about closing the ABD triangle but as it's any other triangle, I didn't see much of an alternative

[image]

Comment: I got the answer as $20$. You can work under the assumption that angle $ACE$ is equal to angle $EAC$. I also obtained the expression for $CD$ in terms of $y$ which is $\sqrt{17.1487 + y^2 +2.14359y}$. Using the law of cosines for triangle $AEC$ we get the value of y which should be $6.56984$. Using the law of sines we obtain the value of $\theta$, then we evaluate the area using the formula $0.5ab\sin(c)$. This should then yield $0.5 \times 10 \times 6.56984 \times \sin(37.5058)$ which is equal to none other than $20$.

Comment: Drop a perp from $C$ to $DE$ and say it is $CH$, then $CH = CJ$. Now area of $\triangle CDE = \frac{1}{2} \cdot 16 \sin 15^\circ \cdot 16 \cos 15^\circ = 64 \sin 30^\circ = 32$ so area of $\triangle ABC$ is $10/16$ times, which is $20$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key is to recognize that since $\overline{AC}$ bisects $\angle DAB$, the altitudes from $C$ to $\overline{DE}$ and $\overline{AB}$ are congruent. Then since $AB$ is $5/8$ times $DE$, the area of $\triangle ABC$ must be $5/8$ times the area of $\triangle CDE$. You already have the the area of $\triangle CDE$, so the area of $\triangle ABC$ follows.

Answer (score 1):

Reflect $B$ across $AC$, we get new point $B'$ on $AD$. Clearly triangles $ABC$ and $AB'C$ are congurent so we have to find an area of the later one. But this is just $AB'\cdot CF/2$. So we need to find $CF$. Let $G$ be the midpoint of $ED$, then $\angle EGC = 30^{\circ}$ and $GC = 8$. Since triangle $CFG$ is half of equlateral triangle we have $$CF = {CG \over 2}=4$$

[image]